# Golang echoフレームワークでURLエンコードされたパスパラメータが大文字と小文字の場合で異なる。

Tags: go, go-echo

GoのWAFであるEcho (https://github.com/labstack/echo) を使ってサイトを作成しています。そこでタイトルのような挙動に出くわしました。

つまり、
`http://localhost:3000/tag/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B1`

というURLと
`http://localhost:3000/tag/%e3%82%aa%e3%83%9e%e3%82%b1`

というURLで得られる値が違うという結果になってしまいます。前者のURLではちゃんとデコードされますが、後者はデコードされずにエンコードされたままの文字列を取得します。なぜこのような挙動がおこるのでしょうか。

パスパラメータの取得部分のコードは以下のようになっています。

**コード例**

```
tagName := c.Param("name")
fmt.Println(tagName)
```

**出力**

前者の場合

```
オマケ
```

後者の場合

```
%e3%82%aa%e3%83%9e%e3%82%b1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>[URL Standard](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0) に従うと、パーセントエンコーディングでは、`%` 記号の後に数字または `A` から `F` までの **大文字** アルファベットを使うと決められています。</del>

上の回答は、[的を射ていません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43398/golang-echo%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%81%A7url%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%A8%E5%B0%8F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%A7%E7%95%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B/43404?noredirect=1#comment44796_43404)。修正します。

---

これは echo の挙動に原因があります。

StackDestroyer さんの[ご指摘](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43398/golang-echo%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%81%A7url%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%A8%E5%B0%8F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%A7%E7%95%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B/43404?noredirect=1#comment44799_43404)どおり、これは echo 側で URL を扱う際 `URL.RawPath` を自前で処理しており、エンコードが大文字か小文字かで差異が生じてしまっています。[`net/url` の godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) も合わせてご覧ください。

おそらく今回のご投稿が発端かとは思われますが、echo の issue トラッカーに[この挙動が報告されています](https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1117)。これが修正されるまで待つか、それぞれのエンコードに対してアドホックに対応するのが良いと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとう御座います。わかりました。小文字だと仕様と違うためデコードされないのですね。しかし、`<a>`要素の`href`にGoの`html/template`を使って日本語を埋め込むと質問のような小文字のものにエンコードされてしまいます。[例](https://play.golang.org/p/eZ4n3w88-oW) なぜこれは間違ったものに変換されてしまうのでしょうか。

Comment: @StackDestroyer `html/template` の挙動について調べていたのですが、これは Go のバグかもしれません。もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: @StackDestroyer `html/template` の挙動とは別に、私が勘違いしていたこととして、RFC 3986 や URL Standard に従うのであればパーセントエンコーディングを **デコードする際は** 、大文字と小文字の違いは吸収される、ということに気づきました。つまりこの回答は正確にはご質問の答えになっていません。もう少し理由を探ってみます（が、少し予定が立て込んでいるので暫くお待ちください……）。

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。自分でも少し調べてみましたが、Echoの[この部分](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/echo.go#L734) で`RawPath==""`であれば`Path`を使うようになっていますが、小文字の場合`RawPath==/%e3%82%aa%e3%83%9e%e3%82%b1`となりエンコードされたままの文字列が使われていました。しかし、大文字の場合`RawPath==""`となりそのあとの`Path`がデコードされているので正しい出力になっていました。[Play ground](https://play.golang.org/p/r65PGPPE-bO) おそらくこのあたりが原因だと考えておりますがどうでしょうか。しかしなぜ大文字と小文字で結果が違うのかがよくわかりません。

Comment: @StackDestroyer 長らくお待たせしてしまってすいません。いくつか調べた結果、(1) `html/template` のエンコードは仕様の勧告と異なるが、これは今回の問題の直接の原因ではない (問題については golang-nuts に投稿済み)、(2) デコードは大文字でも小文字でも良いので回答の最初の版は回答になっていない、(3) StackDestroyer さんのご指摘どおり `getPath` の実装が問題で、ここは `url.EscapedPath` のようにエスケープ結果が複数あることを考慮すべきではないか、ということが分かりました。これらを踏まえ、特に (3) の内容を含めた回答に編集しましたが、そもそも StackDestroyer さんがご発見なさった内容であるため、StackDestroyer さんの方で同じ内容を投稿して頂いても一向に構いません (その場合、こちらの回答は削除いたします)。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コメントあろがとうございます。`url.QueryUnescape(c.Param("name"))` のようにすることで一応正しい日本語の結果を得られました。回答の編集ありがとうございます。